# Optimizing compute shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, compute-shader

I have been doing a lot of different computations in compute shaders in OpenGL for the last couple of months. Some work fine, others are slow, some I could optimize somewhat, others again I could not optimize whatsoever.

I have been playing around with the simple code below (gravitational forces between `n` particles), just to find some strategies on how to increase performance in general, but absolutely nothing works:

```
#version 450 core

uniform uint NumParticles;

layout (std430, binding = 0) buffer bla
{
    double rIn[];
};

layout (std430, binding = 1) writeonly buffer bla2
{
    double aOut[];
};


layout (local_size_x = 128, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;


void main()
{
    int n;
    double dist3, dist2;
    dvec3 a, diff, r = dvec3(rIn[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x * 3 + 0], rIn[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x * 3 + 1], rIn[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x * 3 + 2]);

    a.x = a.y = a.z = 0;
    for (n = 0; n < NumParticles; n++)
    {
        if (n != gl_GlobalInvocationID.x)
        {
            diff = dvec3(rIn[n * 3 + 0], rIn[n * 3 + 1], rIn[n * 3 + 2]) - r;
            dist2 = dot(diff, diff);
            dist3 = 1.0 / (sqrt(dist2) * dist2);
            a += diff * dist3;
        }
    }
    aOut[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x * 3 + 0] = a.x;
    aOut[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x * 3 + 1] = a.y;
    aOut[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x * 3 + 2] = a.z;
}
```

I have the strong suspicion that it is a lot of memory access that slows down this code. So one thing I tried was making a shared variable as a "buffer" and let the first thread (`gl_LocalInvocationID.x == 0`) read the first (for example) 1024 particles, let all threads do their calculations, then the next 1024, ect. This slowed the code down by a factor of 2-3. Another thing I tried, was putting the particle-coordinates in a uniform array (which only works for up to 1024 particles and I use a lot more - so this was just to see, if it made a difference), which changed absolutely nothing.

I can provide some code for the above examples, but I don't think, this would be helpful.

I know there are minor improvements one could make (like using `inversesqrt` instead of `1.0 / sqrt`, not computing *particle n* <-> *particle m* when *m* <-> *n* is already computed...), but I would be interested in a general approach for compute shaders.

So can anybody give me any hints for how I could improve performance for this code? I couldn't really find anything online on how to improve performance of compute shaders, so any general advice (not necessarily just for this code) would be appreciated.

Comment: *and let the first thread (gl_LocalInvocationID.x == 0) read the first (for example) 1024 particles*: The fast approach would be to use a shared variable and let every thread read it's own data into the shared variable. Having 1024 threads read one element is certainly faster than letting one thread read 1024 elements while the other threads are doing nothing. Regarding readability, I highly recommend using a input/output buffer of type dvec3 instead of addressing all doubles on their own. But in the end: If `NumParticles` is large, then the shader will be slow, no matter what you do.

Comment: I guess you are right. But without having tried this approach, I guarantee that this won't be faster then the "not-buffered" version (seeing that using a uniform array doesn't affect performance either)...

Comment: @httpdigest: I just tried your suggestion and got exactly identical results...

Comment: If you use float instead of double, it will instantly get 16 or 32 times faster on most GPUs. If you can't do it for all the variables, maybe see which variables can get away with using float.

Comment: @user253751: I tried that for some other (somewhat similar) algorithm. 16-32 times faster is only true if there is no other bottleneck (like too much memory access). I think, I got maybe 5% speedup...

Answer (score 2):

This operation as defined doesn't seem like a good one for GPU parallelism. It's *very* hungry in terms of memory accesses, as complete processing for one particle requires reading the data for *every other particle* in the system.

If you want to keep the algorithm as is, you can implement it more optimally. As it stands, each work item does *all* of the processing for a particular particle all at once. That's a huge number of memory operations happening all at once.

Instead, split your particles into blocks, sized for a work group. Each work group operates on a block of source particles and a block of test particles (which may be the same block). The test particles should be loaded into `shared` memory, so each work group can repeatedly read test data quickly. So a single work group only does a portion of the tests for each block of source particles.

The big difficulty now is *writing* the data. Since multiple work groups are potentially be writing the added forces to the same source particles, you need to use some mechanism to either atomically increment the source particle data or write the data to a temporary memory buffer. A second compute shader process can run over the temporary buffers and combine the data in a reduction process.

Comment: Is this really a problem? All the threads read all of the other particles at the same time, while the block of particles being updated stays in register memory. The particles being updated should be automatically broken into blocks according to the number of available threads. That seems efficient to me? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I had a similar thought. However, every "buffer-approach" I tried yielded no positive results. Since using a uniform array made no difference at all, this should neither, should it?